# 2 домена на одной VDS

Tags: apache, debian, linux

Всех приветствую.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: необходимо прикрепить два и более доменов к одной VDS, я создал две папки в директории /var/www/%домен%, далее следовал по данному гайду. Но, после ребута апача, ничего не изменяется, то есть, если перейти на домен, он все еще показывает расположение папок в директории /www/.

ОС: debian.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А кто настраивать Апач для двух сайтов будет? Он пока настроен только на один :)
Необходимо настроить Виртуальные Хосты на Вашем сервере.

> В Debian/Ubuntu принято директивы Listen и NameVirtualHost писать в файл конфигурации /etc/apache2/ports.conf, а блоки <VirtualHost></VirtualHost> в каталог /etc/apache2/sites-available по одному файлу на каждый ServerName (сайт) и затем управлять их включением или отключением командами a2endite и a2dissite соответственно, которые создают/удаляют симлинки на конфиг-файлы виртуалхостов в каталоге sites-enabled, на который в свою очередь есть include из главного конфигурационного файла apache2.conf ...

[Apache Virtual Hosts - несколько сайтов на одном сервере](http://easylinux.ru/node/291/)
[Настройка NameVirtualHosts](http://www.alsigned.ru/?p=2218)

## Google рулит !!!

Comment: @Justicet, разобрался, вроде как, спасибо!

Comment: Не за что...